# How to activate XAMPP's apache and mysql for non-admin account on Mac OSX

Tags: apache-2.2, mysql, mac-osx, mac, xampp

I have Mac systems with `os x10.6.8` and above. Installed `XAMPP`.

Is there any way to `START` xampp's apache and mysql by non-amdin user or group?

I searched alot but came up with no solutions. All i want, is to start xampp's apache and mysql from non-admin users. Currently it awlays prompt for administrator password to start or stop the apache and mysql of xampp.

Any help or idea will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start XAMPP on non-admin if you don't mind your Apache server running on a non-standard port. Ports under 1024 require admin permission to be used. Apache (HTTP) uses port 80 by default.

Assuming you are running XAMPP 1.8.x you can change the ports using the XAMPP Control Panel. Click the config button then the Service and port settings button. From here you can change the ports the XAMPP modules use. Change Apache's main port from 80 to (for example) 8000. Then, to access your server from your browser, use `http://localhost:8000` (or other port used).

(If not running XAMPP 1.8, you can change Apache's configuration directly by editing `[XAMPP install location]/apache/conf/httpd.conf` and look for a line that says `Listen 80`. Change `80` to your port number.)